# Why use REST api while you could do everything with `POST`?

Tags: javascript

I've read about documentations on REST api.
From a beginner's point of view, I don't understand why use REST while you could do everything with the `post` method?

For example, if I request the backend to delete one entry, I could simply call `delete_one` as the url in a `POST` request, why bother design a cumbersome `DELETE` request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the goal of REST constraints is to benefit from layered caches. Following the REST architectural style gives you a common language to describe operations and relationships between different operations in a way that would be understood not only by the endpoints (client and server), but also by intermediary components like caches and middlewares. These caches and middlewares may be generic, off the shelf components that weren't built or configured specifically to your application, but only understands the basic semantic of HTTP (or whatever REST flavour you use).

For your particular example, when you use an HTTP DELETE method, you also indicate that caches on that URL should be invalidated:

> If a DELETE request passes through a cache that has one or more stored responses for the effective request URI, those stored responses will be invalidated (see Section 4.4 of [RFC7234]).

This means a subsequent GET command on that URL should retrieve from the origin server, and not from caches.

Comment: But if you don't care about speed of caching, can you get by without adding extra layers of complexity of REST?

Comment: If your user base is small and your application is simple enough, you can always "get by" with anything. Much of the design decisions in HTTP/REST can always be overridden by adding a header or configuration. Understanding REST gives you a foresight into what problems your system likely will fall into and how to solve them with minimals disruptions when you have to scale. Using correct HTTP method is a relatively simple investment that'll help you avoid many common pitfalls. We can't give the kind of advice whether or not you can "get by" with it or not, you have to decide it for yourself.

Comment: @北美38fule we've deployed 100s of services serving millions of users over the last 20 years. We used POST (or mutation) on everything. I've never seen a real life caching system work. I mean when the user makes a request the content is usually different (nature of Web 2)..